# How to install a node module under a different folder than node_modules?

Tags: node.js, npm

With `npm install MODULE_NAME --save` I save all the new modules under node_modules. Is there a way of saving them under a different name?

Answer (score 2):

I glanced through the source code for npm, and I believe the answer is no, you cannot--there are several hard-coded references to the "node_modules" string. Since npm is the package manager for Node, and Node uses the `node_modules` folder to load local modules, I doubt this will change.

Answer (score 2):

The FAQ is clear about it: you can't and you'll never be able to (using normal npm):

https://npmjs.org/doc/faq.html